# The animations in my form do not work properly

Tags: html, css, forms, background, css-animations

Ok so I was following a youtube tutorial for an HTML and CSS form that gave animations. Here is the entire HTML for it..

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="form-box">
      <div class="button-box">
        <div id="btn"></div>
        <button type="button" class="toggle-btn" onclick="login()">Login</button>
        <button type="button" class="toggle-btn" onclick="signup()">Signup</button>
      </div>
      <div class="social-icons">
        <img src="../images/google-logo.png">
      </div>
      <form id="login" class="input-groups">
        <input id="usernameL" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Userid" required>
        <input id="passL" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="password" required>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chech-box"><span>Remember Me</span>
        <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Login</button> 
      </form>
      <form id="signup" class="input-groups">
        <input id="usernameSP" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Userid" required>
        <input id="emailSP" type="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input id="passSP" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="password" required>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chech-box"><span>I agree to terms and conditions</span>
        <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">SignUp!</button> 
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var x= document.getElementById("login");
    var y= document.getElementById("signup");
    var z= document.getElementById("btn");
    function signup(){
      x.style.left ="-480px";
      y.style.left ="50px";
      z.style.left ="110px";
    }
    function login(){
      x.style.left ="50px";
      y.style.left ="-450px";
      z.style.left ="0";
    }
  </script>
```

There is also a js file that called functions as login so I thought that was changed the problem and I changed it to login1 in js file but that didn't do anything...
I'm pretty sure my CSS is also proper so I'm not sure I understand what the problem is..

```
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.hero {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
    url("../images/citybanner.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
.form-box {
  width: 380px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 6% auto;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.button-box {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 35px auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 9px #ff61241f;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.toggle-btn {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}
#btn {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff105f, #ffad06);
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.social-icons {
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.social-icons img {
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.input-group{
  top: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  transition: .5s;
}
.input-field{
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.submit-btn{
  width: 85%;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display: block;
  margin:auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff105f, #ffad06);
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 30px;  
}
.chech-box{
  margin: 30px 10px 30px 0;
}
span{
  color: #777;
  font-size: 12px;
  bottom: 64px;
  position: absolute;
}
#login{
  left: 50px;
}
#signup{
  left: 450px;
}
```

[The form itself. The login and signup buttons work where the color gradient changes but the actual content of the form doesn't change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChnS2.jpg)

Comment: What do you want to achieve here

Comment: What is not working? You have to be more specific and tell us what you have tried.  Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask